# How to insert keyframe data with python?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, import

I am looking for help to insert keyframes with python into my blender project. I already know, that it is possible to export keyframes via python. So it should be also possible to insert keyframes via python.

I wish to insert via python a data like a .xyz file [Xposition Yposition Zposition]. After that I would like to have a finished (camera)path in blender. Is there a way?

Thank you already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no developper but I managed to create a function that adds a specific keyframe on an object in Python.

It goes in 4 steps :

1. check for **animation data** on the object (if none, create some)
2. check for **fcurve** on the desired parameter (if none, create some)
3. create the keyframe
4. set the **interpolation** and easing for the keyframe

Blender **NEEDS** proper animation data and fcurve in order to add keyframes, any less and he'll look at you funny, spamming errors in the console.

Here's the code, with the 2 functions that handles the animation_data and fcurve check, and an example of the function in use :

> ```
> def create_animation_data(target, name):
>     if target.animation_data == None:
>         target.animation_data_create()
>         target.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(name=name)    
>     
> def create_fcurve(target, data_path, id):
>      fcurve = target.animation_data.action.fcurves.find(data_path=data_path, index=id)
>     
>      if fcurve == None:
>           fcurve = target.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path=data_path, index=id)
>         
>      return fcurve
>
> def set_kf_object(obj, data_path="location", id=2, val=0, frame=0, interpolation="BEZIER", easing="EASE_IN"):
>     
>      #if no data, create animation data, new action, and new fcurve
>      create_animation_data(obj, data_path)
>     
>      #store the fcurve
>      fcurve = create_fcurve(obj, data_path, id)
>     
>      #insert the keyframe
>      key = fcurve.keyframe_points.insert(frame=frame,value=val)
>     
>      #set interpolation and easing
>      key.interpolation = interpolation
>      key.easing = easing
>     
>     
>     
> #create a location keyframe on the Z axis, with a value of 1, at frame 36
> #set the interpolation to 'CUBIC' and the easing to 'EASE_OUT'
>     
> cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
> set_kf_object(cube, "location", 2, 1, 36, "CUBIC", "EASE_OUT")
> ```